# How to align the sidebar icon and the logo on the header?

Tags: javascript, html, css

My sidebar icon and logo on the header are not aligned:
[image]
When I try to change them, either one is above or below the other.
As a result, it makes the header bigger too.
I don't know which part of the code should I change.
I hope someone can help me. Thank you in advance.

This is the HTML and  CSS:

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-family: 'Raleway-Bold';
}

.container{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

.container .heading {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color:  #c0392b;
    padding: 30px 20px;
}

.container .heading a {
  float: left;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 90px;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%
  transition: =0.2s;
}

i {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 1em;
  }
.sidenav {
    height: 100%;
    width: 0%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #585756;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
    padding-top: 40px;
  }

.sidenav a {
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 25px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #cfc3c3;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-weight: 500;
    line-height: 40px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(150, 153, 151, 0.1);
  }
 
  
.sidenav a:hover {
    color:  #FFFFFF;
  }
  
.sidenav .closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 25px;
    font-size: 40px;
    margin-left: 100px;
}

.dropdown-container {
  display: none;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.fa-caret-down {
  float: right;
  padding: 10px 0px;
}

.active {
  background-color: #c0392b;
}


@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
    .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
    .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
  }
```

```html
<body>

<div class="container">
  <div class="heading">
      <span style="font-size: 30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776;</span>   
      <img src="images/ChiLin-White.png">
    </div>
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
          <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-home"></i>Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-brain"></i></i>Heisig Method</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-book-reader"></i>Lessons</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-sticky-note"></i></i>Homophones</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown-btn"><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-tools"></i>Tools<i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i></a></li>
                    <ul class="dropdown-container">
                        <li><a href="#">Dictionary</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Flashcard</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Calligraphy generator</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Pinyin Chart (Pronunciation)</a></li>
                    </ul>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-address-book"></i>Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
  </div>      
</div>
<script>
  function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
  }
  
  function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0px";
  }
</script>

<script>
var dropdown = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-btn");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < dropdown.length; i++) {
    dropdown[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var dropdownContent = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (dropdownContent.style.display === "block") {
      dropdownContent.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      dropdownContent.style.display = "block";
    }
    });
}
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: use ```flexbox``` instead of floats

Comment: exactly, floats are outdated. ``onclick`` and writing your scripts in HTML is also not recommended (Check my answer). Good luck!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to align two divs in a container, you can apply flexbox to your container :

```
.container {
  position : flex; 
  align-items: center; 
  justify-content: space-around
}
```

Basically, align-items is for vertical alignment and justify-content is for horizontal-alignment.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the display of `.heading` to *flex* and apply `justify-content: space-between`. This will make space between them. Don't forget that I set the *width* of the `.heading` to *100%*.

```js
var dropdown = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-btn");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < dropdown.length; i++) {
  dropdown[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var dropdownContent = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (dropdownContent.style.display === "block") {
      dropdownContent.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      dropdownContent.style.display = "block";
    }
  });
}

function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0px";
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-family: 'Raleway-Bold';
}

.container {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

.container .heading {
  /* EDITED HERE */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
  /* TILL HERE */
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #c0392b;
  padding: 30px 20px;
}

.container .heading a {
  float: left;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 90px;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100% transition:=0.2s;
}

i {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 1em;
}

.sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #585756;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
  padding-top: 40px;
}

.sidenav a {
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 25px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #cfc3c3;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 40px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(150, 153, 151, 0.1);
}

.sidenav a:hover {
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.sidenav .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 40px;
  margin-left: 100px;
}

.dropdown-container {
  display: none;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.fa-caret-down {
  float: right;
  padding: 10px 0px;
}

.active {
  background-color: #c0392b;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {
    padding-top: 15px;
  }
  .sidenav a {
    font-size: 18px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="heading">
    <span style="font-size: 30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776;</span>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/30/30">
  </div>
  <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-home"></i>Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-brain"></i>Heisig Method</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-book-reader"></i>Lessons</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-sticky-note"></i></i>Homophones</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown-btn"><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-tools"></i>Tools<i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i></a></li>
      <ul class="dropdown-container">
        <li><a href="#">Dictionary</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Flashcard</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Calligraphy generator</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Pinyin Chart (Pronunciation)</a></li>
      </ul>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-address-book"></i>Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```